# Storyboard / Navigation Bar issue in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, storyboard

I'm experiencing a bit of a weird issue and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

In Xcode, using storyboard, I have a view controller that inherits a navigation bar. This is working fine. Where the issue is is that when I add an element to the view controller (ie, UIButton, UILabel, etc) and run the application on my phone, the Y positioning of the element is off by the amount of the height of the navigation bar.

Let's say I wanted to have a UIButton DIRECTLY BELOW the navigation bar, I would have to move it UNDER the navigation bar, to the very top of the view controller on the Storyboard. On my phone it would be directly below (Y positioning) the Navigation Bar.

I'm fairly new to iOS development, so I'm not even sure where to begin. I tried enabling / disabling Auto Layout, which didn't change anything.

Comment: What is your `RootViewController`.? A `UIViewController` or `UINavigationController`.?

Comment: It's actually a Tab Bar controller. Each of the VCs for the different sections were then embedded in their own Nav Controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Click on your view controller, in the Attributes Inspector uncheck the "Adjust scroll view insets" option.

Comment: That didn't have any affect, unfortunately.

Comment: Try the same for the corresponding navigation controller. It's almost 100% a scroll view insets issue.

Comment: You were very close. Xcode, by default, has "Extend Edges Under ____" boxes checked. Once I unchecked the "Top Bar" and "Bottom Bar" options, the problem was fixed.